# how to make html image auto fit sreen in flutter html

Tags: html, flutter

Now I am render some article html page in [flutter html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html), this is my dependencies:

```
flutter_html: 1.3.0
```

now some artilce picture not fit to screen perfect, it margin with the artcle content with too long spaces. looks like this:

[image]

the picture take full of screen and make the head spcace and button space too large, how to make    image auto fit with screen? I have tried this way in my dart code :

```
if (item.content != "")
              Html(
                data: item.content,
                style: {
                  "body": Style(
                    fontSize: FontSize(19.0),
                  ),
                  "img": Style(
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20
                  )
                },
                onLinkTap: (url) => CommonUtils.launchUrl(url),
              ),
```

but it seems not work, and I have already read the manual of flutter html and find solution from internet but did not make any clue. By the way, this is part of my html text:

```
<p><img alt="" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1414041" height="1664" src="https://s3.ifanr.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/VCG41522950244.jpg" width="2500" /></p>
<blockquote><p>「不是不人道，只是不知道；不是做不到，只是想不到。」</p>
<p>这是残障群体常说的一句话。</p></blockquote>
```

Today I tried to upgrade `flutter html 2.0.0`, still not fix this problem.

**Tried 1**: I am now tried to solve it to give a fixed height of image like this:

```
 final Map<ImageSourceMatcher, ImageRender> defaultImageRenders = {
    base64UriMatcher(): base64ImageRender(),
    assetUriMatcher(): assetImageRender(),
    networkSourceMatcher(extension: "svg"): svgNetworkImageRender(),
    networkSourceMatcher(): networkImageRender(height: 400, loadingWidget: loadingWidget),
  };
```

I give a fixed height 400 image but it also have trouble with some little height of icon and so on. how to conditional control height? if height more than 400, then fixed 400. less than 400, just keep the original height is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IMG` tag has both `width` and `height`. Since the widget is being rendered with a `maxWidth`, the width is constrained but the height uses the specified value of `1664`. I have tested with both versions (1.3 / 2.0) on Flutter 2.

[image] [image]

Removing the `height` attribute makes it work as expected:

[image] [image]

If you can control the HTML, just omit the size from all `IMG` tags. Otherwise you can modify the string to void the height attribute, something like this should work:

```dart
// add a dash in front of height attribute to disable it
// original = <img src="xxx" height="123" width="456" />
// replaced = <img src="xxx" _height="123" width="456" />
final replaced = original.replaceAllMapped(
  RegExp(r'(<img[^>]+)(height=)', caseSensitive: false),
  (match) => match.group(1) + '_' + match.group(1),
);
```

I won't recommend going with the regex solution though. It's error prone and may break unexpectedly. Another option is switching to [flutter_widget_from_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html) (it's my package), it works with your HTML unchanged.

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html/flutter_widget_from_html.dart';

const kHtml = '''
Foo

<p><img alt="" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1414041" height="1664" src="https://s3.ifanr.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/VCG41522950244.jpg" width="2500" /></p>
<blockquote><p>「不是不人道，只是不知道；不是做不到，只是想不到。」</p>
<p>这是残障群体常说的一句话。</p></blockquote>

Bar

''';

class DemoScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('flutter_widget_from_html')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: HtmlWidget(kHtml),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: this flutter_widget_from_html package is nice, I have switched to this from flutter_html after a day trying to scale the image full screen width.

Answer (score 1):

My PR at https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/pull/630 addresses this issue, please watch for it to be merged. Thanks!

Comment: Not merge now.@Tanay Neotia

Comment: I cannot control that unfortunately, it must be reviewed then merged. Hopefully within the next few weeks it is merged, until then I suggest to wait.